# node.js: writing test cases for social networking like APIs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, integration-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm developing APIs for social networking web application for learning perspective. When I started to write test cases I stuck around how to organize/write test cases.I'm initially proceeding like this:

**First setup global data base initialization:**
I need some users' auth tokens to test my routes so I decide to set up these information at global context. Also there are other information that also need to setup at global context so I'm setting that too.

**Then for each route:**
I start to write test cases and thought that I would write test cases in 
such a way that each route test cases would be independent to each other.

**and after completing all test suites:**
I thought that I would clean up my data base.

---

**The problems** with this approach I'm facing are:

Say I want to test four routes named **/users** , **/users/:id/my_invites** , **/send_invites**, **/response_invites**. And further suppose I'm only interested in writing test cases for GET request and response for **/users** , **/users/:id/invites** and POSTing data in the case of others. 
**/send_invites**, **/response_invites** definitely trigger some actions on the server side that modifies the data base state.

As we see that these routes effect the state of other routes' data say one user sends invites to another user and gets response true/false, so for that user his request was successful but how to ensure that another user actually received the invitation if we don't checking his received invitation documents(i.e through another route) in the first route test cases. Means **/send_invites** effects the  **/users/:id/my_invites** .

---

because these routes are dependent on each others

```
So The questions I want to ask are:
```

how to write test cases for these routes so that each route would be independent ?

I tried with three dummy testing users in the global context and trying all sort of combinations for them in all test suites.My test suit presently deals with more than one routes to check 1 route true functionality.

```
Can anyone suggest me better solution for writing test cases for the above mentioned scenarios?
```

May be my question is too long or not clear. Please let me know and help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

First the bases EACH test case should have a fresh new state. That means that before you check one scenario, you want to flush your database and insert your new data prepared to test that case scenario. You can use a real database o mock one with data in-memory or however you prefer.

Second, each endpoint potentially affects a lot of tables in your database. So it's perfectly normal to check the state of your data, independently of the tables to check that the information is correct.

And well mocha and other test frameworks have functions that help you to do that. Like beforeEach and afterEach to set up and tear down your data before each test case.